# The performance to bfs traverse a Binary Tree

Tags: python, algorithm

I am practicing on problem  [Binary Tree Level Order Traversal - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-level-order-traversal/)

> Given a binary tree, return the *level order* traversal of its nodes' values. (ie, from left to right, level by level).
>
> For example:
>   Given binary tree `[3,9,20,null,null,15,7]`,
>
> ```py
>  3
> / \
> 9  20
>  /  \
> 15   7
> ```
>
> return its level order traversal as:
>
> ```py
> [
> [3],
> [9,20],
> [15,7]
> ]
> ```

The BFS solution

```py
class TreeNode(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class Solution:
    def levelOrder(self, root: TreeNode) -> List[List[int]]:
        from collections import deque 
        if root == None: return []
        queue = deque([root])
        res = []
        step = -1
        while queue:
            step += 1
            size = len(queue)
            if len(res) < step + 1:
                res.append([])

            for _ in range(size):
                cur = queue.popleft()
                res[step].append(cur.val)
                #stretch 
                if cur.left:
                    queue.append(cur.left)
                if cur.right: 
                    queue.append(cur.right)
        return res
```

The performane

> Runtime: 44 ms, faster than 75.27% of Python3 online submissions forBinary Tree Level Order Traversal.
>
> Memory Usage: 13.4 MB, less than 5.64% of Python3 online submissions for Binary Tree Level Order Traversal.

Please notice the cumbersome checking:

```py
            if len(res) < step + 1:
                res.append([])
```

After removing the condition checking as

```py
class Solution:
    def levelOrder(self, root: TreeNode) -> List[List[int]]:
        from collections import deque 
        if root == None: return []
        queue = deque([root])
        res = []
        step = -1
        while queue:
            step += 1
            size = len(queue)
           # if len(res) < step + 1: #remove the condition checking 
           res.append([])

            for _ in range(size):
                cur = queue.popleft()
                res[step].append(cur.val)
                #stretch 
                if cur.left:
                    queue.append(cur.left)
                if cur.right: 
                    queue.append(cur.right)
        return res
```

The performance changed to

> Runtime: 56 ms, faster than 19.04% of Python3 online submissions forBinary Tree Level Order Traversal.
>
> Memory Usage: 13.5 MB, less than 4.52% of Python3 online submissions for Binary Tree Level Order Traversal.

Logically, they are of the same performance, why reported such a major difference?

Comment: The runtime is in milliseconds, so the difference seems pretty minor to me. The same goes for memory usage. Do they run several benchmarks and compute an average? What are the instance sizes? Did you try multiple runs of the same code to see whether what you call such a major difference also occur?